# Как исправить белые углы у CardView?

Tags: android

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
<com.sothree.slidinguppanel.SlidingUpPanelLayout
    android:id="@+id/sliding_layout"
    android:gravity="bottom"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    sothree:umanoPanelHeight="100sp"
    sothree:umanoShadowHeight="0dp"
    sothree:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/main_toolbar"
    sothree:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent">

<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        sothree:cardBackgroundColor="#2366E7"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:focusable="false"
        sothree:cardCornerRadius="30dp"
        sothree:cardElevation="0dp"
        android:id="@+id/dragView">
```

Comment: Corner Radius поставить 0 dp

Comment: @Романыч мне нужны закругленные углы

Answer (score 0):

Что бы убрать белые углы в CardView(у меня он вложен в com.sothree.slidinguppanel.SlidingUpPanelLayout), установить атрибут umanoOverlay=true в SlidingUpPanelLayout[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Как я мог это узнать из вопроса?

Comment: @Романыч соре, моя ошибка

Comment: Переименуйте вопрос, и дайте более подробную информацию,чтобы люди смогли найти вопрос и ответ.